# Is it possible to unify std::wstring behavior in VSVC and GCC?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, utf-8, wstring

Here a little code that reads a line from UFT-8 file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);

    auto inputFileStream = std::wifstream("input.txt");
    const auto utf8Locale = std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>());
    inputFileStream.imbue(utf8Locale);

    std::wstring line;
    std::getline(inputFileStream, line);
    std::wcout << line << std::endl;

    inputFileStream.close();
    return 0;
}
```

When I build it with the Visual Studio Visual C++ compiler, I got the next result:

> test τεστ тест

as expected.

By when I use MinGW with the GCC compiler, I got

> 琀攀猀琀 쐃딃쌃쐃 䈄㔄䄄䈄

As you understand, it's not the expected result.

1. Does any *simple* way exist to fix the output for GCC to the expected string?

**OR**

2. Does any *simple* way exist to use UTF-8 for both MSVC and GCC?

---

Answer (thanks for **Igor Tandetnik** and **Remy Lebeau**):
Seems, we must specify endian mode explicitly, because MSVC and GCC have different defaults. So

```
new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>()
```

should be used.

Fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <locale>
#include <fstream>
#include <codecvt>

int main()
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U8TEXT);

    auto inputFileStream = std::wifstream("input.txt");
    const auto utf8Locale = std::locale(std::locale(), new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>());
    inputFileStream.imbue(utf8Locale);

    std::wstring line;
    std::getline(inputFileStream, line);
    std::wcout << line << std::endl;

    inputFileStream.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like a bug in the runtime. Those Chinese characters have their bytes reversed - e.g. `琀` is `U+7400` while `t` is `U+0074`. It's as if the codec assumes that `wchar_t` is big-endian, but then it's printed as little-endian.

Comment: Windows uses UTF-16 little endian, but [according to cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_mode) `std::codecvt_mode` defaults to big endian instead. Maybe VC++ handles that internally whereas MinGW does not? You can specify little endian explicitly in the optional `mode` template parameter of `std::codecvt_utf8`, eg: `new std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t, 0x10ffff, std::little_endian>`, then it should always output a UTF-16LE `wstring` on Windows.

Comment: Assuming you're comparing console output. One thing to check is whether the programs produce the same output when it is redirected to a file (or check in the debugger that `line` contains same bytes). My guess is that the blame is either on `wcout` (in general, iostreams cannot do unicode console output in Windows and you'll have better luck with stdio) or on the settings of the consoles (fonts, codepages).

Comment: I don't use Windows but I would be tempted to avoid `std::wifstream` and load `UTF-8` in a normal `std::ifstream` and then convert the text to `std::wstring` after loading it.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, it's true. I've printed separate characters and got «feff 0074 0065 0073 0074 0020 03c4 03b5 03c3 03c4 0020 0442 0435 0441 0442» with MSVC and «fffe 7400 6500 7300 7400 2000 c403 b503 c303 c403 2000 4204 3504 4104 4204» with GCC.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, thank you, it works. The last questions: does `0x10ffff` has any named constant? And seems, `std::codecvt_utf8` has already deprecated; does another way exist to convert strings?

Answer (score 0):

For your second question, one option is to limit the use of utf16 and `std::w`-prefixed stuff to the cases when you need to exchange utf16-encoded strings with the operating system. This happens when you receive arguments in `wmain`, open file with `_wfopen`, call Windows API function, etc. Otherwise, you would store, get from the user and return to the user utf8 strings using `char` type (`char*`, `std::string`, etc). Conversion between utf8 and utf16 can be done with `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte`, bypassing the retarded c++ encoding api. The place where this does not work well is console input/output. Overall, you can output utf8 to the console if the user sets `chcp 65001` and a ttf font. At least in Windows 7, you will also have to make sure not to split a character between two write calls, otherwise it will not print correctly (this also implies you cannot use `std::cout`, because msvcrt will call `putc` for every byte separately, and you'll need to use `puts`, `fprintf`, etc instead); I heard that this was fixed in Windows 10, but cannot confirm. Reading utf8 from the console with file api does not work as far as I know; if you want that, you'd need to detect that stdin is attached to a console and use console api instead.